# Unit testing react-redux connected components with Mocha/Chai

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, react-redux, chai

I'm trying to test a connected component, which I've exported both as a connected component and as a plain one as per the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35578985/3019008) by Ashwin Van Dijk.

All my tests for dumb components work fine, and the app runs fine (the connected component works).

The component is pretty straightforward-just displaying a list retrieved from state:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import Plot from './plot';
import Spinner from 'react-spinkit';

export class Dashboard extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchMessage();
        this.props.fetchPlots();
    }

    render() {
        const plots = this.props.plots;
        if (plots === undefined) {
            return (
                <div className="dashboard loading">
                    <Spinner name="three-bounce" />
                </div>
            );
        } 

        return (
            <div className='container-fluid dashboard'>
               **(all my stuff lives here)**
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        message: state.auth.message,
        plots: state.auth.plots
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Dashboard);
```

The test doesn't even run-it gives me a funny looking error about css:

```
C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\loaders.css\loaders.css:14
@-webkit-keyframes scale {
^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\react-spinkit\dist\index.js:40:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Users/BaruchKogan/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/TrellisReact/src/components/dashboard.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at loader (C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Users/BaruchKogan/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/TrellisReact/test/components/dashboard_test.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at loader (C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:220:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:217:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:469:10)
    at loadAndRun (C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:360:22)
    at rerun (C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:387:5)
    at C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:395:7
    at StatWatcher.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TrellisReact\node_modules\mocha\lib\utils.js:174:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at StatWatcher.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at StatWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1501:10)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like Mocha is trying to load a CSS file as Javascript.  I have solved this problem in the past using [ignore-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-styles).  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34375878/379358

Comment: Works! New error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655144/react-redux-app-testing-action-creator-containing-axios-get-call But that's a new can of worms. Can you put your comment as an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Mocha is trying to load a CSS file as Javascript. I have solved this problem in the past using ignore-styles. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34375878/379358

(Moved from comment per request)